# See other users badges

Tags: support, badges

Is it possible to see what kind of badges other users have been awarded? I'm not talking about the amount of badges they have, but what they have gotten them for.

Comment: Go to the profile page of a user, to their "activity" tab. Click on the "badges" section, then on a specific badge. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Aaah, I never saw that activity tab:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can see that in their profile page on *Activity* > *badges*, like [mine here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/245360/patrick-hofman?tab=badges)

Also you can see who was awarded what badge, on [the Badges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/tumbleweed). Clicking the badge will show you an overview who was awarded the badge. In the case of Tumbleweed, it will show the question the badge was awarded for.